# trying to align an image to the right margin and text to the left margin (Android application)

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the layout I am using:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="30dip"
>

  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal" 
        >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/poi_name" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/internet" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/internet"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="20sp"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>
    ...
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

However, the text appears aligned to the left but the image appears at the same height than the text (as expected), but horizontally centered in the screen. Why is it not aligned to the right ?
I tried with different combinations of the `android:gravity` attribute at the `RelativeLayout` without success.

The `maxHeight` attribute of the image is set using 'sp' units because I want the image to be proportional to the text it is accompanying. Is that correct ?

Thanks for your feedback.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the answer of @danh32 I managed to solve this using a `LinearLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout`. But just out of curiosity: if someone knows what was the problem with the `RelativeLayout` of my example, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using textview's drawableRight attribute to display the image, instead of a standalone imageview?  You should be able to change the textview's width to fill parent and set the drawableRight as your internet drawable.

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/poi_name" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/internet"
    />
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @danh32. In fact I was not aware of the drawableRight attribute. I need the image to attach an onClick listener to it in order to open a browser when clicked. Is it possible to attach the same listener to the image if I declare it using the attribute you mention ?. The onClick listener should be activated only when clicking the image, not the text that is on the left.

Comment: Ah, then perhaps you should not use the drawableRight attribute. You can only specify click targets at the view level, so you cannot have the image react, but the text not react.  The way I normally solve this problem is by setting the textview's width="0dp" and it's layout_weight="1". This lets the textview eat up any extra space in your layout, and should push your imageview to the right. This only works in LinearLayouts, though. Not RelativeLayouts.

Comment: If I change to LinearLayout and add the attribute layout_weight="1" to the text view as you say then it works. Apparently the width="0dp" was not necessary (but I am sure you told me that for a reason, in which cases I need to set that attribute to zero then?). I also replaced the layout_alignParentLeft="true" and layout_alignParentRight="true" in the Text and Image views by gravity="left" and gravity="right".

Comment: Setting the width="0dp" is just an optimization so that the width doesn't get computed twice during inflation, so it's not really necessary. Leaving it at wrap_content will cause that to get computed, and then replaced when the height and width are recomputed using the 'layout_weight' attribute.